# Xcode can’t find headers from an embedded framework

Tags: xcode

I have two frameworks installed through Carthage, located in `${PROJECT_DIR}/Carthage/Build/` (the default Carthage path). In my app’s target, I have dragged both frameworks to the Embedded Binaries section as described in the docs. Now no matter what I do, Xcode complains that it can’t find the headers from these two frameworks. What I have tried:

- The headers are there, I can click through them in the Xcode tree view and in Finder.
- In the frameworks’ Xcode projects, the headers are listed as Public under *Build Phases* → *Headers*.
- Setting *Header Search Paths* to `${PROJECT_DIR}/Carthage/Build/**` doesn’t help. (WTF?)
- Making a clean build and deleting all derived data did not help.

Tried both in Xcode 6 and Xcode 7 beta 5. This is an OS X target, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the *Header Search Paths* wrong. Getting it right did not help, but entering the right path to *Framework Search Paths* did. Go figure.

Comment: Can you share EXACTLY what you placed in your path?  (I'm lost on the correct format for the path suffix) . thx.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing and re-adding the frameworks

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, several times, even made sure there’s no mention of them in the Xcode project file, then readded, problem reappeared.

Answer (score -1):

Due to an Xcode defect, it cannot accommodate a search path that has a directory name with a space in it. This causes Xcode to fail to find framework includes at the end of the search path.

Example: `#import <C0re/C0re.h>`

C0re is a custom framework that has many years of macOS development knowledge built into it (since 1984). I want to use it from a central location for all my projects: `~/Development/Projects/Frameworks Library/`
[image]
and inside `~/Development/Projects/Frameworks Library/` I have:
[image]

In the project within which I want to use the framework I have:[image]

And it fails to find the import/include:
[image]
I then:

1. Removed the framework from the project (just delete the reference not the framework itself)
2. Removed the space from the folder name in the framework's path (aka `Frameworks Library` to `FrameWorksLibrary`)
3. Added the framework to the project again
4. Changed the `System Frameworks Search Paths` under `Build Settings` to remove the space (for me `FrameWorksLibrary`)

and with no editing of any source code... **The Error Is Gone:**

[image]
**Note**: (*another related Xcode defect*... Xcode variable updates...)
If you are using user-defined variables or `Custom Paths` under `Locations` in `Preferences`, you will need to perform some bogus edit on the entry you made in `System Framework Search Paths` to trigger Xcode to re-evaluate the system variable(s) you are using in your paths. Otherwise you can change the Xcode system variable all day long and not have change in the ability for Xcode to find the header. 
And if your path is really long like mine really are, you may never see that the path is not changing...

And for one more kick in the pants, if you named your `Derived Data` folders with a space (vs `DerivedData`) and try to reach into them directly for the framework build... yep, it'll gitcha.

Comment: You have to wonder why, when adding a framework, can't Xcode automatically add that framework to the search paths? Something IDEs in the '90s could do...

Comment: Escape spaces in paths with \ e.g. ~/Development/Projects/Frameworks\ Library/. Also for <C0re/C0re.h> use Header Search Paths not System Header Search Paths.

Comment: I used drag and drop to get Xcode to put the path in there.  When Xcode accepted the drag, it should have escaped it.

Comment: When you drag in a path it puts it in quote marks which removes the need to escape so I'm not sure what your problem is.